# Maximum sum of any contiguous subarray of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of integers, find the maximum sum of any contiguous subarray of the array. For example, given the array `[1, -2, 3, 10, -4, 7, 2, -5]`, the maximum sum of a contiguous subarray is `18` (`[3, 10, -4, 7, 2]`). This is the problem statement

My solution(not working for all test cases) :

```js
function maxSubarraySum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0;
  let currentSum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    currentSum += arr[i];
    if (currentSum > maxSum) {
      maxSum = currentSum;
    } else if (currentSum < 0) {
      currentSum = 0;
    }
  }

  return maxSum;
}

console.log(maxSubarraySum([1, -2, 3, 10, -4, 7, 2, -5])); 
// Should output 18
```

failed testcase:

```
input:  [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
expected output: -1
output:0
```

I have been debugging my code for a long time now, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the case where ```currentSum === maxSum ``` ?

Comment: [4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3] why is it not the sum of all the numbers

Comment: You reset `currentSum` to zero when it's less than zero, but what if the input array has all negative numbers, some closer to zero and others farther? The max sum might be less than zero.

Comment: @SrushtiShah I believe that will never be the case as every time we go to the loop, some value is added or subtracted from the `currentSum`, so it can never be equal to `maxSum`, at least till the loop is running

Comment: Your logic is a bit odd. Why would currentsum be set to 0 like that? They are asking for the maximum sum, not the maximum sum if it happens to be greater than 0.  Perhaps start by thinking of this array [-1]

Comment: The comment from @cmgchess is important: if the array contains all positive numbers, then no sub-sequence can sum to more than the entire array (discounting the degenerate case of some values being 0, where there are multiple answers).

Comment: @AHaworth thanks, that completely makes sense, works now

Comment: this is actually a famous problem and can be found in clrs. i had a java code with me which uses divide and conquer. i converted it to [js](https://gist.github.com/cmgchess/bbb43b02b01bcc7642ce83010ea91b9d)

Comment: plenty of duplicates: [JavaScript algorithm question: get the find the contiguous subarray which has the largest sum from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558214/javascript-algorithm-question-get-the-find-the-contiguous-subarray-which-has-th), [Maximum subarray problem - min value solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408197/maximum-subarray-problem-min-value-solution)  [Javascript function that finds largest subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730006/javascript-function-that-finds-largest-subarray), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So:

1. First get all subarrays.
2. Calculate sum of each subarray.
3. Return the largest sum.

I can't see that you are trying to get all the subarrays in your code?

One solution would be:

```
function largestSubSum(arr) {
  // get all subarrays
  let subs = arr.map((x, i, a) => a.slice(i).map((x, i, a) =>
    a.slice(a, i))).flat().filter(x => x.length !== arr.length && x.length);
  // get sums
  let sums = subs.map(x => x.reduce((a, c) => a + c));
  // return max sum
  return Math.max(...sums);
}

console.log(largestSubSum([1, -2, 3, 10, -4, 7, 2, -5])); // => 18
console.log(largestSubSum([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5])); // => -1
```

**In detail, how this implementation works**

*Getting all subarrays:*
Use map to go through the array and get new arrays that are slices, first from index 0, then index 1 etc. For each of those arrays map through those too and slice in the same way. Because of how maps in maps works we now have an array of arrays of arrays, so flatten it to one single array of arrays. Then, using filter remove every array that has the same length as the whole original array (that's not an subarray) and every empty array (length is 0/falsey). We now have an array of all subarrays.

*Gettting the sum of each sub array:*
Simply map through the array of arrays and use reduce on each array to calculate the sum of it. Now we have an array of sums.

*Getting the largest sum:*
Send all the sums as separate arguments to **Math.max** that will return the largest number.

Comment: can you explain your code a bit, btw it works, thanks

Comment: I will edit the answer....

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `.filter(x => x.length !== arr.length);`?

Comment: Ah, well spotted. Forgot a length property. But no, not only: Two conditions. checking that it isn't as long as whole array and not an empty array. Edited the code. Thanks! (If we kept empty arrays the reducer would complain in the next step.)